# What prevents tor from configuring ALL entry nodes to act like bridges?

Tags: bridge

What prevents tor from configuring ALL entry nodes to act like bridges? This would dramatically improve the speed for connecting through bridges

Comment: The IP Address of all entry node is publicly known and blacklisted by adversaries while the IP Address of Tor bridges is kept private.

Answer (score 1):

> What prevents tor from configuring ALL entry nodes to act like bridges

Bridges are unlisted and are only advantageous because they're unlisted, so using listed relays as "bridges" is almost exactly the same as using Tor without bridges.

> This would dramatically improve the speed for connecting through bridges

No, there is no reason that this would be the case.